# What does the 「いるん」in だれか好きな人がいるんですか。

Tags: words

Everything else in this sentence I understand except 「いるん」. Can someone tell me it's meaning/purpose? Why can't I just say だれか好きな人ですか。?

My textbook translates the sentence as: "*Is there someone you like?*"

Comment: In short, いる...か here is “is there?” for animate beings and  んです is used when one ether “explains” a situation or (like here) asks of an “explanation”. Without いる it would probably sound like a choice from a list. See, e.g., https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-nda-ndesu-noda-nodesu/

Answer (score 1):

です does not assert whether something exists or not.  In a construction like

> ＡはBです

You're asserting that "A" is a "B" where both "A" and "B" are nouns.

If you just say,

> Aです

Then you're saying, "**I** am an A" since the presumed topic will be 私.  It never means, "There is A".

But, if you want to say that "there is *something*", then you have two choices.

> 好きな人がいます。

There is someone I like.

> 好きな食べものがあります。

There is a food that I like.

The difference between います and あります being whether the word marked by が is a living thing or not, respectively.  In plain form, these become いる and ある.

You could ask,

> だれか好きな人がいますか

That would make sense.  It would mean "Is there someone you like?"

In plain form, this would read

> だれか好きな人がいるの

Or something similar.  However, it's a bit blunt.  And the person asking is curious (perhaps because of something *you* said or other circumstances).

> だれか好きな人がいるのですか

with the insertion of の, they asking something more along the lines of

> Is it the case that there's someone who you like?

This の is an explanatory marker.  It's suggesting that there's more going on than just a question of whether there's someone you like.  We don't have anything like this in English.  But, in Japanese, you usually add markers like this to your sentences as a way of indicating where you're coming from.

This explanatory marker の often gets reduced to ん as in your example sentence

> だれか好きな人がいるんですか

So, while in English, "is it the case that..." sounds clunky or unnecessarily verbose, in Japanese the insertion of の
gives it a more human/natural sound.